# how to get java codes after using react native bulid a complete app?

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native

In react native android JS code will be translated to java code, so can 
 I have some way to get this code?I searched android's fold, but can not find. Can u give me some advises?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how react native works. Your javascript code is not compiled or translated to java or ObjectiveC/Swift. It stays as javascript itself.

All of your javascript code, written in many files, gets minified and bundled into one single javascript file. Usually this file is `main.jsbundle`. This javascript code then runs on a separate thread in the device, and it sends messages to a native thread to create `Views` and other components on the native side.

This communication between native and javascript side happens through the react native bridge. Also, it is the bridge that delegates all the user interactions to the javascript side so that your business logic can handle them.

tldr: Javascript code does not get compiled to java, but stays as javascript itself.